# AWS EMR error for spark application cache

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, amazon-emr

We have steps running on EMR using spark-scala. Everything is working fine for 2 years but for last 10-12 days the yarn applications get closed randomly and the step failed to retrieve the closed application.
Below is the error from the log

```
ERROR ApplicationMaster: Exception from Reporter thread.
org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.ApplicationAttemptNotFoundException: Application attempt appattempt_1531902138329_0769_000004 doesn't exist in ApplicationMasterService cache.
    at 

    org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ApplicationMasterService.allocate(ApplicationMasterService.java:439)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.impl.pb.service.ApplicationMasterProtocolPBServiceImpl.allocate(ApplicationMasterProtocolPBServiceImpl.java:60)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.proto.ApplicationMasterProtocol$ApplicationMasterProtocolService$2.callBlockingMethod(ApplicationMasterProtocol.java:99)
```

It happen for random steps.I had checked with server memory while steps are running there is not much load and plenty of storage is available.

EMR=emr-5.2.0
Spark 2.0.2

Comment: Did this happen after an update to the code or has it been the same for 2 years?

Comment: @Simon no there is no change in code for 2 years its the same.

Comment: @Yogesh Were you able to solve this ?

Comment: Any solution to this problem so far?